# How to exclude header from reloading when using reloadData in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, header, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I have an `UICollectionView` using `CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout` to mimic header behavior in `UITableView`. Inside the header there is `SegmentedControl` to control data on the `UICollectionView`. So what I want is to reload the data when I tap the segment (calling API) and perform the `reloadData` but it always called the

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So what is the best approach to reload only the data not the header, because when `reloadData` the header will reload too, and the segment will back to the first state.

here is the code from my `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UICollectionReusableView *reusableView = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        SegmentHeaderView *collectionHeader= [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"Header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"Popular", @"Lelang"]];
        [segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [NConfig FlatButtonGray];
        segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorBoxOpacity=1;
        segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [NConfig FlatButtonOrange]};
        segmentedControl.selectedTitleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [NConfig FlatButtonOrange]};
        segmentedControl.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleBox;
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = HMSegmentedControlNoSegment;
        segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationNone;
        segmentedControl.shouldAnimateUserSelection = NO;
        [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0 animated:YES];
        [collectionHeader addSubview:segmentedControl];
        reusableView = collectionHeader;

    }
return reusableView;
}
```

any advice? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you store the selection only inside the view layer where it can get lost. You really should set a property with your new selection index when the user selects a different segment. Then you can react to this changed property by reloading your data. Before you return the header view you set the selected segment to the index you previously stored. That way the selection will never get lost.

In addition to this you also should avoid reloadData and instead only reload the items that actually changed.